# Use an async method instead of a sync one

Tags: c#, asynchronous

As far I've been to figure out in order to turn out a `sync` method to `async`:

```
private async void RefreshScreen()
{
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            this.refreshContent();
            this.refreshTokens();
        }
    );
}
```

Isn't there anyway to get it using a more elegant way?

**EDIT**

As you can figure out `RefreshContent()` and `RefreshTokens()` are engaged on several calls to a webservice.

This webservice client implementation provides `sync` and `async` ways to call a method:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetUrlAsync ()
{
     ApiResponse<string> localVarResponse = await GetUrlAsyncWithHttpInfo();
     return localVarResponse.Data;
}

public string GetUrl ()
{
     ApiResponse<string> localVarResponse = GetUrlWithHttpInfo();
     return localVarResponse.Data;
}
```

Currently, we're using `"sync"` methods and certainly, we want to move on using `async` calls.

Example:

```
public Enumerable<Element> GatherElements()
{
    return yield new Element() {
        Field1 = RESTClient.GetMethod1(),
        Field2 = RESTClient.GetMethod2(),
        Field3 = RESTClient.GetMethod3(),
        Field4 = RESTClient.GetMethod4(),
        Field5 = RESTClient.GetMethod5(),
        Field6 = RESTClient.GetMethod6(),
        Field7 = RESTClient.GetMethod7()
    };
}
```

I don't want to wait until all rest calls are completed, I want to return all Elements regardless of whether each `Field` is fullfilled.

I don't know if I've explained so well.

Comment: use `Task` instead of `void` if it is not event handler.

Comment: Why using `Task` instead of `void` is more suitable? Could you provide any sample?

Comment: Sample: put `throw new Exception()` inside `Task.Run` and then execute your `RefreshScreen` somewhere - and you notice that no exception was thrown

Comment: @Jordi there are a ton of articles that explain this. `async` is just syntactic sugar that allows you to use `await` in the body. Unless your method returns a `Task`, you can't await for it to complete. `async void` methods are only meant for event handlers or fire-and-forget methods

Comment: More elegant way: change `refreshContent` and `refreshTokens` method to be asynchronous then you can just call them without `Task.Run`

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - `async void` methods meant **only for event handlers**

Comment: Ehm, aren't those methods expected to update some UI? That's what I deduce from their names. Hence they'll likely need to run in the UI thread to access those UI elements (excepts some other mechanism for accessing the UI, e.g. bound ViewModel, is used).

Comment: How Could I run the async task on Main UI thread?

Answer (score 3):

You're approaching the problem "backwards". Instead of trying to figure out how to "make this method async", you should start at the other end.

For example, what does `refreshContent` do? Is it performing some I/O that is slow, perhaps hitting a web API or database? Then you start with those low-level web/database calls. Make those asynchronous **first** (both `HttpClient` and Entity Framework have built-in asynchronous support). Then `await` those calls, and let `async` grow from there.

The compiler will guide you if you take this approach, e.g., it will recommend that you change return types to `Task`/`Task<T>` when you add `async`. As others noted, you should [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). You also will not need to use `Task.Run` unless you're doing some CPU-heavy operations that you need to offload.

Eventually, you'll end up with an `async Task RefreshScreen`, which you can call from an `async void` event handler.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. I've edited the post. I've posed the problem from another approach....